# How can we use json.dumps directly in class constructor, instead of calling it via separate function?

Tags: python, confluent-kafka-python

How can we use `json.dumps` directly in the constructor, instead of calling it via a separate function?

```py
def json_serialize(obj, *args):
    return json.dumps(obj)

class KafkaProducer(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        config = {
            "key.serializer": json_serialize,
            "value.serializer": json_serialize,
        }
        self.producer = SerializingProducer(config)

    def produce(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.producer.produce(*args, **kwargs)
        self.producer.flush()
```

When I use produce method of KafkaProducer class it works with the above implementation. As json_serialize function is used to do only `json.dumps(obj)`.

If I tried this using `json.dumps` direct in `KafkaProducer` as given below and then call produce a method of class it won't work. gives error as:

```
    KafkaError{code=_KEY_SERIALIZATION,val=-162,str="dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"}
```

```py
class KafkaProducer(object):

    def __init__(self, config):
        config = {
            "key.serializer": json.dumps,
            "value.serializer": json.dumps,
        }
        self.producer = SerializingProducer(config)

    def produce(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.producer.produce(*args, **kwargs)
        self.producer.flush()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't. `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` functions must have the following [signature](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/_modules/confluent_kafka/serializing_producer.html): `Callable(obj, SerializationContext) -> bytes`. `json.dumps` doesn't accept `SerializationContext` as a parameter, so you need to use some wrapper around it. That's why you need `json_serialize` function.

Comment: without using the extra wrapper function also works. for that you will need to use lambda function. **"key.serializer": lambda x,y: json.dumps(x)**

Comment: So, lambda function will be your wrapper).